# How to get string of what actionresult have result in c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult IndexAct()
{
    return View();
}
```

I want to know what this actionresult return.

I want to code something like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var x = IndexAct();
    var res = x.ToString();
    return View();
}
```

see that in this code x is first action that is called IndexAct(); Now someone please tell me how to get the result. What I actually want to do is get the response string.

Comment: try return View(res);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516234/asp-net-mvc-convert-return-action-resultview-to-string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585758/asp-net-mvc-how-to-covert-an-actionresult-to-string

Comment: I call XY problem. What are you trying to ultimately accomplish here?

Comment: @Kaf actually I am looking for get the string

Comment: @JasonEvans I want to get the string (response String) in my variable. How I can do it.

Comment: @millimoose Actually I want to implement caching by saving the response to text file. I want to use Text caching because my authetication model (mysql) doesn't fit good if I try to use outputcache.

Comment: @user101292 OutputCache works as an action filter whatever that is - so why not write your own filter? Since ASP.NET MVC is open-sourced, you can look at how the existing cache works and modify it.

Comment: @millimoose Very good, I will definitely goes with this option. :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you process the response in the controller using the following way:

```
public ActionResult IndexAct()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IndexAct(string myString)
{
    // check myString here
    return ...;
}
```

Where myString is an input field on your form.
Your IndexAct.cshtml will look like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Question</legend>
    @Html.TextBox("myString");
  </fieldset>
}
```

The text typed in the textbox will be posted and available in your controller.